# I want to run lip sync and speech parallel in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, parallel-processing, speech

I am working on a virtual assistant and having difficulty in parallel running speech(audio) using the library Speech.Synthesis and the lip sync.
How am I doing lipsync?
I have an image wpf control and a database of images, in which there are a lot of vismey images. I change the images according to the text.
If I run lip sync and audio sequentially, they work good. But when I want to do parallel using Task.Run audio works good but lip sync does not execute.
I am not sure if I am using a good approach for lip sync or not.
Kindly guide me if I can do something better than that or how can I run them parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would be using the [RxFramework](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) to emit “events” out of the speech routine by calling the OnNext function. I would then subscribe to these “events” in the lip sync part of your code. You can use LINQ to filter or buffer the stream coming out of the speech part of your code which is quite cool